# Raid 5 on two scsi buses with different maximum speeds

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, raid5, hp-smart-array, scsi

I'm quite a noob, I'm trying to set up as a study machine an old HP ProLiant DL385 G1.

I've configured a RAID 5 out of six SCSI 3.5" HDDs using:
- Smart Array 6i controller;
- (4 x SCSI Ultra320 36,4GB disks, 15K) AND (2 x SCSI Ultra3 36,4GB disks, 10K), all on the same local SCSI bus.

Now the disks should run on the SCSI bus at most @ 10K, 160MB/s, as imposed by the slowest Ultra3.

If I put the two groups of disks on two different SCSI local buses, would the overall performances of the array be improved?
The two-buses configuration requires an optional terminator board...

Comment: I cannot resist asking: so it is not possible to create a single array raid 5 out of six disks on two different scsi buses?

Comment: You can, yes... if you use a dual-channel controller like a Smart Array 6402 or 6404.

Comment: Thank you, I'll check out again the documentation for the Smart Array 6i!

Comment: good luck with it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't bother. The [split-bus/split-channel (aka "Duplex Mode*") design](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/kb/docDisplay?javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.prp_ba847bafb2a2d782fcbb0710b053ce01=wsrp-navigationalState=docId%253Demr_na-c00355176-6%257CdocLocale%253D%257CcalledBy%253D&javax.portlet.tpst=ba847bafb2a2d782fcbb0710b053ce01&ac.admitted=1398868309117.876444892.199480143) was only helpful in separating OS and data drive activity and offering an opportunity to use multiple Smart Array RAID controllers. It would break your 6 bays into 2 + 4 bays.

Just use the system as-is, though. The stakes are low, and this is very old equipment/technology.